# Have code to connect to TFS 2013 from Powershell. Is there an equivalent for Azure DevOps Server 2019?

Tags: powershell, scripting, azure-devops-server-2019

This may be a pretty dumb question but I couldn't find an answer.

I have been working with TFS 2013 since it came out, and now I'm on to Azure DevOps Server 2019.  For TFS, I had an easy way of connecting to the instance using the following code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

$serverUri = 'https://tfs.myorg.com/tfs'
$tfsConfigurationServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory]::GetConfigurationServer($serverUri)
$tpcService = $tfsConfigurationServer.GetService('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamProjectCollectionService')
```

All I'm trying to find is the correct Assembly Name, version, and PublicKeyToken for ADO 2019 Update 1.1.    I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) which lists what appears to be the assemblies I need, but there are only C# examples on how to use them (I don't know C#).  Can anyone advise what the new Add-Type assembly info would be, or how I can find it?  I built most of my scripts based on info from the "Hey, Scripting Guy!" blog, but he's retired.  I'm guessing the.. classes?.. would need to change as well (the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory] portion of the code).

I know I need to get into the REST APIs and understand how to use those.  In the interim, is there an equivalent to the code above for Azure DevOps Server 2019?

Comment: Did you *try* with the old SOAP object model assemblies? They generally continue to work between different versions.

Comment: Yes, that's how this all started :D